# tar exclude tag

Tags: tar

I have the following folder structure: `myFolder` and `testFolder` have same folders underneath it and I want to exclude only `my1` from `testFolder` and not `myFolder`.

```
myFolder
+---my1 
+---my2
+---my3

testFolder
+---my1
+---my2
+---my3
```

I am trying to use exclude tag along with included folders while creating a tar file.
This is what i have, but it does not seem to work.

```
tar -cvf base.tar "/sam/myFolder" "/sam/testFolder" --exclude="/sam/testFolder/my1"
```

Comment: This question is about using tar, I don't see anything related to perl, as the title of the question would suggest.  Thus I think this question is better suited for superuser.com.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `tar` does not use PCRE for the exclude pattern, but regular shell wildcard expansion.  So this is not a Perl question at all.

Comment: Your command is correct. It does exactly what you request. Perhaps post the output of "ls -lR /sam" and the output of the tar command to shed some more light on the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a techie in perl. This is what i found after a bit of research.

The command was correct. The only problem was with the paths. we need to be careful with the relative paths.

folder structure:  D:\tools\Packet\sam\

D:\tools\Packet>tar -pcvf base.tar "sam/myFolder" "sam/testFolder" --exclude "sam/testFolder/my1"

-cvf
-pcvf 
both work fine.